# android layout as emptyview of a listview programmatically made

Tags: android, listview, layout, addition

I have an `Activity` extends `ListActivity`, where I had to create a `ListView` programmatically (no xml).

To set up an emptyView for it the only way that worked was the following code I found in another thread:

```
    TextView emptyView = new TextView(this);
    ((ViewGroup) getListView().getParent()).addView(emptyView);
    getListView().setEmptyView(emptyView);
```

now my goal is to do the same using a layout instead of a `TextView`, so I made an xml with its id and put it this way:

```
    View emptyView = findViewById(R.id.empty_view_xml);
    ((ViewGroup) getListView().getParent()).addView(emptyView);
    getListView().setEmptyView(emptyView);
```

but it doesn't seem to work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your problem:**

Because your view (`empty_view_xml`) doesn't exist in the activity xml, so calling `findViewById(R.id.empty_view_xml);` will return a `null` value, and setting null as emptyView will do nothing.

Your current code: `.setEmptyView(emptyView);` is similar to `.setEmptyView(null);`.

**To solve this:**

You need to inflate your custom xml, then add it as EmptyView:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(YourActivity.this);
View emptyView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.empty_view_xml, null, false);
((ViewGroup) getListView().getParent()).addView(emptyView);
getListView().setEmptyView(emptyView);
```